# JTable with JComboBox inside cell programmable opened

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Hey all I have been to figure this out for a few hours now. Currently I have to click on the cell and then click again in order to open up the dropdown (which is a date picker).

What my goal is-is to use code once it detects a click inside the cell that's in the correct column.

The code I have tried are:

```
comboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
```

and

```
table.editCellAt(0, 4);
```

and

```
comboBox.showPopup();
```

Currently I do have that/cells as being editable. Though when I run the program and click on one of those cells this is the error it give me:

I'm defining my combo box like so:

```
public static JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
```

And I am calling this from another class.

> class1:
>
> ```
> if (selCol == 4) {
>     try {
>              TblWithDropdown.dropBox();
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>              e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
> ```

And now my other class:

> TblWithDropdown class:
>
> ```
>  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
>  public static JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
>
> public class TblWithDropdown {
>    public static void dropBox() throws InterruptedException {
>       comboBox.showPopup();
>       //table.editCellAt(0, 4);
>       comboBox.setPopupVisible(true);
>    }
> }
> ```

The error it gives me is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: component must be showing on the screen to determine its location
>       at java.awt.Component.getLocationOnScreen_NoTreeLock(Unknown Source)

Visually this is what my table with the combox looks like:

[[image]
[[image]

Help would be great in order to solve this issue!

**UPDATE 1**

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

```
_al = alldata.fillInData("SELECT fname FROM users");
String[] testers = new String[_al.size()];
TblWithDropdown.comboBox = new JComboBox(_al.toArray(testers));
TblWithDropdown.table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3)
                      .setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(TblWithDropdown.comboBox));
JXDatePicker res = new JXDatePicker();
res.setFormats(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM));
res.setDate(new Date());
res.getMonthView().setDayForeground(Calendar.SUNDAY, Color.RED);

DatePickerCellEditor testser = new DatePickerCellEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"));

testser.setClickCountToStart(0);
testser.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"));
TableColumn dateColumn = TblWithDropdown.table.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
dateColumn.setCellEditor(testser);
```

Comment: @TT that would take a large amout of code.. and it prob. wouldn't run anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can try is rather than calling `showPopup` directly, is to have this as a `focusGained` listener for the editor `JComboBox` component:

```
public static JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
```

```
// initialize editor component
comboBox.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                comboBox.showPopup();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply TT. but that also seems to have the same error as my original one had. I've placed the new code up in the OP under **UPDATE 1**

Comment: That new code did work without errors but did not work to drop the dropdown when clicked on. I added more code to the OP since I may be incorrect about it being just a combobox. Seems its called **DatePickerCellEditor** with a **JXDatePicker** inside the cell.